# Unable to right float a element within a div

Tags: html, css

My requirement looks very simple but I'm not sure whats wrong here.

I have div and within it I have 2 divs..Im unable to right float it..

html

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="cart-id">cart</div>
    <div id="acct-id">acct</div>
</div>
```

css

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:2;
}
#navigation{
    width:5%;
    background-color:red
}

#cart-id{
  float:right;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:.5%;
  margin-right:5%;
  color:green;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6y6r/)

Comment: `#navigation{ width:5%;..` ?? 5% width?

Comment: Look for `width:5%;` its to small

Comment: They are floating right, but your navigation width is only `5%` so they are floating right inside that `5%` space. Either remove it, or add `float:right` to your `#navigation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works.. but only when the screen is full screen, you should make `#navigation` width from `5%` **to** `10%` width. and you see that the `li's` are `floated right`.

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/C6y6r/2/)**

If you want the navbar to be floated right, you should set `float:right` on `#navigation` instead of on the `<li>`

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/C6y6r/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
width:5%;
```

to fix your issue.

OR change the width of it to something higher

Answer (score 0):

your width isn't big enough.
change to this:

```
#navigation{
    background-color:red
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also note the missing ';' at the end of the line in:

```
background-color:red
```

Comment: That doesn't mather when it is the last item inside the curly-brackets in the css...